# Get a deleted record using SObject Rows returns "The requested resource does not exist"

Tags: api, error, sobject, fields, id

I'm using the [SObject Rows API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm) to get the fields values of a given record. It works fine on existing records but when used on deleted records it returns with an error of `{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}`.

As the docs note, `Accesses records based on the specified object ID. Retrieves, updates, or deletes records.`

Can I retrieve deleted records with this API? if not, is there a way to retrieve the deleted records field values/data for a given record ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### QueryAll

QueryAll will return records that have been deleted because of a merge or delete. QueryAll will also return information about archived Task and Event records. QueryAll is available in API version 29.0 and later.

**URI**

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,isDeleted+FROM+Account
```

For retrieving additional query results if the initial results are too large:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm

---

**Edit**

Query Based on Id

```
/services/data/v35.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,isDeleted+FROM+Account+WHERE+Id‌​='0019000001cH0ud'
```

Comment: But QueryAll does not let me query by a specific record, am I right? I don't want to query ALL my deleted records, just the ones I define by their ID

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld try with `queryAll/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,isDeleted+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name='test'`

Comment: I only have the ID, not any of the other fields

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld then use Id field `/services/data/v35.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,isDeleted+FROM+Account+WHERE+Id='0019000001cH0ud'`

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld let me know if you have any issue here?